# Does Trello support auto assign?

Tags: trello

I want to be assigned automatically to every ticket on a board. It's only me that is using this board, but I do not remember to myself every time I open a ticket.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible right now.

You can send an email to `feature-ideas@trello.com` to propose this feature.

Answer (score 20):

A hidden gem when you forgot to assign yourself to a card is to simply hover the mouse pointer over the card and press space. This is not the auto-assignment solution you where looking for, but it's a great time-saver when you need to assign yourself to many cards.

https://trello.com/shortcuts

Comment: This is acutally really useful, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a "template" card, with all the features you use in every card you make. Assign yourself to this template.

When you need a new card, copy the template. All your check lists and whatnot will be copied and you will be automatically assigned to the copy also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to auto assign but here are the best 3 alternatives I use:

1. Hover your mouse over a card and pressing the space key assigns you to that card.
2. Hover your mouse over a card and press 'm' and select yourself or members that way too.
3. Hover your mouse over a card and press 'e' (for edit) and then you can "change members".

Option 1 is the quickest.

https://trello.com/shortcuts